# Live streaming from iOS to Wowza and viceversa

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming, live, wowza

I need to know something more about the integration of Wowza with iOS. I need to publish the live camera streaming to Wowza from the iPhone and also to see live streaming from the server. There are libraries or something which help to reach the goal?

Comment: Perhaps use the Wowza GoCoder app to send the stream in?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at commercially or openly available libraries like those:

- https://wmspanel.com/mobile_library
- http://realtimelibs.com
- https://kickflip.io